# Duplicate and let image appear when hovering on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I let a image duplicate and appear on a other place when hovering on it?
The duplicated image should appear in the `div` with the class `thumbnailPreview` and the class `previewImages` should be hidden. This action should least as long as the user hovers the image.

I've made this little graphic:

[image]

**Before hovering the thumbnail Image:**

```
<div class="previewImages">
      <img src="/cat.png">
</div>

<img class="ImageAttributeList" src="/dog.png">
```

**When hovering the thumbnail image** (`div` `.previewImages` *is hidden*)

```
<div class="previewImages">
      <img src="/cat.png">
</div>

<div class="thumbnailPreview">
      <img src="/dog.png">
</div>

<img class="ImageAttributeList" src="/dog.png">
```

I need some kind of script but i have no coding experience

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are using jQuery?

If you know how to install jQuery and have installed it properly on your page then this should work:

```
$('.ImageAttributeList').mouseenter(function () {
  $('div.previewImages')
  .hide()
  .after('<div class="thumbnailPreview">' +
         '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">' +
         '</div>');
});

$('.ImageAttributeList').mouseleave(function () {
  $('div.previewImages').show();
  $('div.thumbnailPreview').remove();
});
```

Make sure you're adding the above event listeners only once the DOM (your elements) have loaded.

You can do this by wrapping it with jQuery's `$(document).ready` or putting it in a `<script>` tag within the body, etc.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is preinstalled. I need this solution for a onlineshop

Comment: @hippolas_cage this is a really well-made question, super interesting too. Test out my code above ^^ and let me know what doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it and let you know :-)

Comment: That solutions works thank you :-) But there is a problem: I use this code in a category overview with many items. So all items that appear after the div, that accutally should fire the action, are triggered and change thier image. I hope you understand my problem

Comment: @hippolas_cage you will have to use `.parent()` and `.find()` a few times each (maybe) to find the correct `div.previewImages`. If you put your actual HTML in the question I can write it for you.